# I receive MissingProviderToken error with APNs

Tags: ios, go, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am sending a push notification in Golang with a certificate on iOS via APNs and I receive MissingProviderToken error. Indeed, debugging the code, I see that the client has a null token. I use sideshow library,
[sideshow/apns2](https://github.com/sideshow/apns2).

```
cert, err := certificate.FromP12File("./certificates.p12", "*filepassword*")

if err != nil {
   log.Fatal("Cert Error:", err)
}
notification := &apns2.Notification{}
notification.DeviceToken = *deviceToken*
notification.Topic = "*appbundleid*"
notification.Payload = []byte(`{
      "aps" : {
         "alert" : "Hello!"
      }
   }
`)

client := apns2.NewClient(cert).Production()
res, err := client.Push(notification)
```

Does this token need to be passed by the certificate?

I tried two different certificates created by my company but still returns 403 MissingProviderToken.
I tried also
`client := apns2.NewClient(cert).Development()` 
Can I manually pass token just to try?
Did anyone experience this or where am I making a mistake?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, did you resolve it?

Comment: I had the wrong certificate. Changing the certificate did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this guide [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide: Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html), it means
`No provider certificate was used to connect to APNs and Authorization header was missing or no provider token was specified`.

So, change the certificate.